# Consume(timeout) with timeout > max.poll.interval.ms not triggering rebalance

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

From my understanding of the `max.poll.interval.ms` configuration, if my consumer doesn't consume() at least once in that interval, a rebalance will be triggered.

However, I'm not being able to trigger that rebalance. Am I getting this configuration wrong?
Here's a sample of my code:

Relevant consumer configurations:

```
BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
GroupId = "group1",
SessionTimeoutMs = 10000, 
HeartbeatIntervalMs = 3000, 
MaxPollIntervalMs = 11000
```

What I'm doing:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow}: Consume()");
   var message = consumer.Consume(new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds: 30));
}
```

This prints every 30s the "Consume()" message. Shouldn't it instead trigger a rebalance after 11 seconds due to max.poll.interval.ms = 11000 ?

I'm using Confluent.Kafka 1.3.0

Comment: I think the C# client does a non-blocking poll